# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS no longer able to boot normally

Tags: 12.04, boot

Until recently, I was able to boot into 12.04 LTS without any problems.  Now, after the splash screen (the one that says Ubuntu with the 5 dots below it), I get a plain black screen, and nothing happens.  The backlight is on (I can tell because I can switch it off using function keys on the laptop).

I tried booting into recovery mode.  From there, I selected "enable networking".  I see a lot of text messages on the screen, the last of which is something like:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda7: clean 503648/5873664 files, 16228870/2348972 blocks
```

After that, nothing happens.  In desperation, I hit CTRL+C and see this:

```
The disk drive for / is not ready yet or is not present
```

While this doesn't sound good, after a few seconds Ubuntu boots and I'm able to use it normally.  What's going on here, and how can I get Ubuntu to boot properly without having to go through the recovery mode?

Below are some relevant files:

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
mtpfs           /mnt/nexus7     fuse    user,noauto,allow_other,defaults 0 0

# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=d67a32d7-aeb2-499c-b854-5a5588ab44d0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=37aa594e-d42b-4104-8ceb-8bf5f535fbbc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

/var/log/dmesg: http://pastebin.com/jG6pj6vs

The interesting part of dmesg appears to be around the 40 second mark (line 929) -- this is approximately the time that I hit CTRL+C:

```
[   41.431376] init: friendly-recovery main process (1136) killed by INT signal
[   41.832821] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   53.659693] Adding 4028412k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4028412k
[   54.017887] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   54.123538] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (2043) terminated with status 1
[   54.266949] init: failsafe main process (2086) killed by TERM signal
[   54.313791] init: friendly-recovery post-stop process (1323) terminated with status 1
```

It seems like some processes are hanging and preventing the normal boot.  Perhaps when I hit CTRL+C, those processes are killed and boot can continue.  How can I find out what those processes are, given their IDs (the numbers in the parentheses)?

/var/log/boot.log:

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda7: clean, 503673/5873664 files, 16231307/23489792 blocks
initctl: Event failed
modem-manager[2121]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Nokia

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin ZTE

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Huawei

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Sierra

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin MotoC

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin SimTech

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Wavecom

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin X22X

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Novatel

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option High-Speed

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Option

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Samsung

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Linktop

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Ericsson MBM

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Gobi

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Generic

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin Longcheer

modem-manager[2121]: <info>  Loaded plugin AnyData

 * Starting system logging daemon                                        [ OK ]
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon                                           [ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting bluetooth daemon                                             [ OK ]
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                                            [ OK ] 
 * Setting sensors limits                                                [ OK ] 
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon                               [ OK ]
 * Starting LightDM Display Manager                                      [ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation                            [ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon                 [ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon                              [ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
```

I forced a file system check on boot (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=77771) and it did not find any errors.  What else could be wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried booting into older versions of the kernel.  I have 2 other versions accessible from the boot loader:

- 3.2.0-31-generic
- 3.2.0-29-generic

3.2.0-31 doesn't work (same problem), but 3.2.0-29 works!  Does this mean that  there is a bug in the kernel?

**EDIT**

I followed the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot to diagnose my problem.  I updated the boot options as instructed:

- removed quiet, splash, $vt_handoff
- replaced $linux_gfx_mode with text

The system booted correctly!  After more fiddling, I determined that the quiet, splash and $vt_handoff are irrelevant -- replacing $linux_gfx_mode with text is what's fixing the problem.

What's going on here?  Where exactly does the bug live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've worked out what the problem was.

I noticed that window dragging had become unbearably slow, and began to suspect a video driver problem.  After reinstalling the proprietary ATI drivers as described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI, my problem went away.

Do as the followings:

- On the left launcher bar, click "System Settings" icon
- Then "Additional Drivers",
- Then wait the system to search for proprietary graphics driver
- Choose the first one and click "activate", which will trigger the installation process
- And finally type in the password to allow change.

[image: Use UI to install Graphic driver]